# Are the fields in my Access database correctly linked?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, relationship

[image]I am creating a database in MICROSOFT ACCESS for a hospital with the following requirement:

The fields must be fillable on a form and only a form (the Dr. does not want to work with tables).

Altogether, the form is sending data to 8 different tables divided into 1) Patient Information; 2) Consultation Information; 3) Protective concern; 4) Case Summary; etc...

In any given case, all of the fields from a table may not need to be filled out on the form . In other words, the protective concern section may be left blank for a week and then filled out.

regarding how the relationships between fields and tables have been defined, I have linked all of the tables together through the ID field, in other words:

*Patient Information ID -> Consult. Info. ID

Patient Info ID -> Protective Concern ID

Patient Info ID -> Case Summary

Consult Info ID -> Protective Concern ID

Consult Info ID -> Case Summary ID

Protective Concern ID -> Case Summary ID*

My concern is whether or not I have correctly linked the fields so that each individual case reported is going to be mapped to itself whether or not a table has any entries.

Comment: This is easier to comprehend if you paste a picture of your DB diagram into your question.  Access can easily provide one.

Comment: The info you have provided makes it sound as though you are linking the tables on the primary key of both tables. to use PatientID as an example - it will be a primary key in the patient table but there should be Patient ID in (eg) consultation table as a FOREIGN KEY. then you link tables on primary key -> foreign key

Comment: Here is a picture of the diagram - I can't post an actual picture because of the confidential nature of the tables, but here is a model. 

In response to the suggestion to link them to a foreign key, would I have to make a foreign key per other table in the current table?